# Trouble understanding Unsorted Lists and generic data types?

Tags: c++

So we learned about Unsorted Lists in my Comp Sci 2 class today - the teacher mentioned that with Unsorted Lists you can create generic data types that simulate any data - however the operations on that data are defined to be something specific.  The example the book gives is along these lines:

```
#include “ItemType.h”
class UnsortedType // declares a class data type
{
public : 
// 8 public member functions
     void UnsortedType ( );
     bool IsFull ( ) const; 
     int GetLength ( ) const ; // returns length of list
     ItemType GetItem ( ItemType item, bool& found);
     void PutItem ( ItemType item ); 
     void DeleteItem ( ItemType item ); 
     void ResetList ( );
     ItemType GetNextItem (); 
private :
// 3 private data members
     int length; 
     ItemType info[MAX_ITEMS]; 
     int currentPos;
};
```

My question is: when I try to recreate something like this, do I have to make some class specifically called ItemType? Or is ItemType a placeholder for whatever object you want to store in the Unsorted List? (for example, could you replace ItemType with say: phonebookContacts where phonebookContacts class is an object that contains contact information for people in a phonebook?)

Comment: This sounds like a question for your teacher.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I actually did this, but her explanation was very...short and unhelpful.  I'm at my first semester here and it turns out I got the less...helpful of the two CompSci 2 teachers comparatively speaking.  I've asked questions like this a couple times before so I tend to kind of not ask questions anymore and figure things out through the internet/book.  But since the book failed, now I'm here!

Comment: `ItemType` is not a standard C++ type. Since you have a header called `ItemType.h` the best thing to do would be to look in there to see how it's defined.

Comment: Sounds like `ItemType` should be a template argument?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could replace ItemType with phonebookContact.

Just replace each ItemType with phonebookContact, and #include a header like  phonebookContact.h instead of ItemType.h.  The header phonebookContact.h would need to contain the definition of the phonebookContact class as ItemType.h presumably contains a definition of the ItemType class.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on c++ templates. Templated classes.
The following is an example http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/